# creating a list from a discrete function in mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to make a list of lists {{a},{b}...}, but instead I'm building a list of non-list terms {{{a}},{{b}}...}

First, I started with a discrete function:

```
 f[n_]:=RandomReal[BinormalDistribution[{c[[n, 3]], c[[n, 1]]}, ...........
```

Second, I made a list of lists by:

```
 d = Array[f, 100]
```

Outputs:  `{{{1.64219, 0.0231185}}, {{0.690885, 0.00599381}},......`

Which can not be read by `SmoothDensityHistogram`:

> SmoothDensityHistogram::ldata: {{1.64219,0.0231185}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Flatten` a single level in your list of lists. Essentialy you're squeezing out a singleton dimension in your 3d array, making it 2d:

```
In[22]:= mylist = {{{1.64219, 0.0231185}}, {{0.690885, 0.00599381}}}

Out[22]= {{{1.64219, 0.0231185}}, {{0.690885, 0.00599381}}}

In[23]:= Dimensions[mylist]

Out[23]= {2, 1, 2}

In[24]:= mymatrix = Flatten[mylist, 1]

Out[24]= {{1.64219, 0.0231185}, {0.690885, 0.00599381}}

In[25]:= Dimensions[mymatrix]

Out[25]= {2, 2}
```